# Error: No instance of overloaded function "mbed::Ticker::attach" matches the argument list

Tags: c++, overloading, interrupt, mbed, ticker

I set up the ticker here:

```
Ticker readSample;


uint16_t* sample() {
    samples[sCount]=sensor.read_u16(); 
    sCount++; 
    if(sCount == 159) {
        sCount = 0;
    }
    return samples; 
}
```

And called it in main function here:

```
int main() {
readSample.attach(&sample, 0.0125);
```

I get error code 304, no idea how to overcome this. Cant find a straight answer that's transferrable to my work.

Error: No instance of overloaded function "mbed::Ticker::attach"  matches the argument list in "main.cpp", Line: 142, Col: 17

First time poster, total amateur at coding, any and all help/advice is massively appreciated.

Comment: Why have you reversed the tag edit back to C? C does not use `::` or overloading, and you clearly state the file is `main.cpp`. You might get some help on the C++ pages. As a first-time user you might benefit from reading [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: changed because I though I had originally mistyped it and went back to correct. thanks for your help though now I know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of an attached function has to be void. You cannot return uint16_t*. Here is the function declaration.

```
attach (Callback< void()> func, float t)
```

You can learn more about Ticker class here. https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v5.11/apis/ticker.html